# Android Animation doesn't repeat

Tags: android, animation

I have this very simple Animation for ImageView

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="1300"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
```

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash_logo);
    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    imageView.setAnimation(animation);
    animation.start();

}
```

the problem is that the animation does not repeat, I tried this:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    animation.start();
}
```

and the animation just repeats for two times then stops

Comment: No need to override the `onAnimationEnd` as you have already set the animation repeat count as INFINITE. Remove that function.

Comment: `animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);` is incorrect. There is no such mode. It can be `RESTART` or `REVERSE`

Comment: its dose not work with both solutions mr.robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works for me

```
        RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotate.setDuration(500);
    imageView.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set repeatCount and repeatMode in xml, and remove from code

```
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

Android studio doesn't give you suggestions for this attributes, you should write manually.

Comment: objectAnimator is not allowed here

Comment: Ok i tried your code, and found solution, you should set repeatCount and repeatMode in xml, this work for me                      android:repeatMode="restart"
  android:repeatCount="infinite", android studio doesn't give you suggestions for this attributes